# Visual Studio Code will not load tkinter package

Tags: python, tkinter, visual-studio-code

I have been using VS Code to learn python. Everything has always worked great until i started trying to use tkinter. For some reason VS Code does not recognize anything from tkinter. I am trying to run this simple code:

```
from tkinter import * 
Tk()
```

And i get this error:

```
Exception has occurred: NameError
name 'Tk' is not defined
```

But when i launch IDLE3 and run that same code, it works just fine and loads the blank window. I've googled and cannot figure out what the problem is. Can someone please help me figure this out.

Thanks

Comment: Which python is it calling? Ipython?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. I'm still pretty new to python.

Comment: One thing of note. I downloaded PyCharm and loaded my project and its doing the same thing. But when i create a brand new project and change nothing it seems to work just fine, no issues at all. So it must be some settings in my project, and i have no clue how to fix it.

Comment: If you are new to python, maybe anaconda spyder IDE could be of interest for you.

Comment: Have you checked that the Python interpreter selected in VS Code matches the one you're using for IDLE?

And FYI, I would advise against using `import *`. It's really only meant for use from the REPL as it makes it hard to tell where things are coming from in your code.

Comment: did you name your file "tkinter.py"?

Comment: in ubuntu this fixed for me when i reinstall tkinetr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also had the same issue.
The problem was that the file I was trying to run was saved as tkinter.py
Renamed the file to tkinter_tutorial and it worked fine.
Also, you can check this link
https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues/941